# Ruby module_function, invoking module's private method, invoked in class method style on module shows error

Tags: ruby, module, private-methods

**test_module.rb**

```
  module MyModule
    def module_func_a
      puts "module_func_a invoked"
      private_b
    end

    module_function :module_func_a

    private
    def private_b
      puts "private_b invoked"
    end
  end

  class MyClass
    include MyModule
    def test_module
      module_func_a
    end
  end
```

**Invoking module function from class**

```
  c = MyClass.new
  c.test_module
```

**Output 1:**

```
$ ruby test_module.rb 
 module_func_a invoked
 private_b invoked
```

**Invoking module function on module in class method style**

```
ma = MyModule.module_func_a
```

**Output 2:**

```
 module_func_a invoked
 test_module.rb:5:in `module_func_a': undefined local variable or method `private_b' for MyModule:Module (NameError)
 from test_module.rb:31
```

As can be seen from the Output 1 and Output 2 *when including the module in a class, no issue occurs when a module's private method gets invoked from a module function
while in case when directly invoking the module function on the module in class method style the module's private method, invoked from module function, is not found.*

Can anybody make me understand the reason behind above behavior and whether invoking module function (which in turn invokes module's private method) on module in class method style is possible or not? If possible, then what rectifications are required in my code to do the same?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It works when you include the module in a class, because then all of the module's methods get included in that class (the `self` in `module_func_a` points to `MyClass`, which has also the `private_b` method).

In the other situation self points to `MyModule`, which does not have private_b method. If you wanted it to work both ways, you'd have to either declare `private_b` as a module method as well, or simply add the line `extend self` to `MyModule`, so that all it's methods would become module methods.

Comment: Thanks.This works.I tried extend self to MyModule and it is working.However it seems that in this case private seems redundant and has no effect.So is it that in cases like mentioned ones we cannot create private methods? For e.g say I need to create a utility method which should be used only by module instance or module functions and should not be exposed to the users of the module

Comment: You can't and that's why I prefer to use delegation.

Comment: @pysho - Can you please provide me an example or provide me a link which provides details on how to use delegation you mentioned about?

Answer (score 3):

`module_function` does copy your `module_func_a` into the metaclass but not its dependencies.

So when calling `module_func_a` from an object, you get the other method `private_b`. But calling it on the module itself fails because `private_b` is not a module function.

You should use module_function for `private_b` too and it should work.